# installed pytorch1.0.1 for OS X with pip3 but cannot import, what can I do?

Tags: python, python-import, pytorch

I have already installed pytorch for MacOS 10.14 with pip3, but I can not import it in the python script. What should I do?

System: MacOS 10.14

Python3: v3.7

```
➜  ~ pip3 list
Package     Version    
----------- -----------
numpy       1.16.2     
Pillow      5.4.1      
pip         18.1       
pycairo     1.17.1     
pygobject   3.28.3     
setuptools  40.5.0     
six         1.12.0     
torch       1.0.1.post2
torchvision 0.2.2.post3
virtualenv  16.1.0     
wheel       0.32.2     
➜  ~ python3 
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
>>>
```

Comment: What about `python3 -m pip list`? Does it appear there? There's no guarantee that `pip3` is your `python3`'s `pip` after all...

Comment: @AKX You are right, it didn't appear there. Actually, I didn't fully understand the relationship between the pip3 and my python3's pip. I will be so grateful if you tell me about the relationship. And how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon my comment:

There's no strict guarantee that a `pip3` wrapper script somewhere on your system is related to the `pip` package manager/module for your `python3` binary. That wrapper may be created by a different installation of Python – maybe your system's own, maybe something else. (You can see where the script is located with `which pip3` and see which interpreter it uses with `less $(which pip3)` and looking at the shebang line at the top.)

Each version of Python you have installed has its own site-packages directory, which contains the globally (as far as that version is concerned) installed packages. Fortunately, `pip` can be run exactly equally as the wrapper script would with the `-m` switch, so to be *sure* Torch and Torchvision get installed into your `python3` (which appears to be Python 3.7.0 at this time),

```
python3 -m pip install torch torchvision
```

should do the trick.

However, globally (well, interpreter-globally, as discussed above) installed packages should be avoided, since you can easily get into hairy conflicts when you're working on multiple projects. You should instead use virtualenvs to separate your library installations from each other – the `venv` module is included in Python these days, and the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) has a guide on it. (Other options are pipenv and poetry, but it's worth knowing the lower-level tooling.)

Comment: You totally solved this issue and also help me to understand the relationship between python and package managers, thank you so much!